# mouse remapping doesnt work in Blender - middle click

Tags: mouse, logitech, blender, xinput, remapping

I try to remap my logitech MK 705 mouse buttons, in Xubuntu 14.04

for this i used :

> xinput set-button-map

I wanted remap my **Wheel left**  to be a **Middle click**. ( I need to use a lot of the middle click in 3d Software, but the orginal middle click is too hard to press, )

but, when i execute:

> xinput set-button-map < id > 1 2 3 4 5 **2** 6 7 8 9 10

it works in my web browser - Firefox - to close tabs but doesnt in Blender 2.74 to turn objects.

when i tried for an experimental purpose this input:

> xinput set-button-map < id > 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

in Firefox all remapped buttons worked as Middle Click, 
but in  **Blender** only the left and right wheel didnt work as Middle click the others remapped works well.